# Get any address from subdomains with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to get any urls from subdomains to root (mvc boot)

I use from this code for root folders:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ boot.php?url=$1 [L]
#this code good working ...
```

But for subdomain, how do I get files that do not exist?

```
#The following code is worked,but not get 404 folders Or files(!-d,!-f,!-l)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mySubDomain.domain.com [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /../boot.php?url=$1 [L]
```

---

How can I add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

to this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i solved this problem** ...

i create .htaccess file in subdomian directory

and add this code to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /../boot.php?url=$1 [L]
```